# Improve Nexus 4 Vibration Intensity

Tags: settings, vibration, nexus-4

This is basically the same question as posed here: [Increase vibrate strength](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28851/increase-vibrate-strength)

I thought there might be a different answer for the Nexus 4, however, seeing as how it's a different manufacturer and the OS has changed slightly.

I came from using a Nexus S which had a really good vibrate. With the Nexus 4, however, even with nothing else in my pocket sometimes I can't feel it. I'm used to being able to get a slight buzz or something if I set my phone down on my desk but with the Nexus 4, the best I can hope for is a slight buzz if it's on a hard surface. Touching papers or something else? Better hope you were looking at the phone, otherwise you're going to miss incoming calls.

For other Nexus 4 owners, is this a noticeable issue with your phone? Maybe mine is slightly defective. If not, is there any way to boost the intensity or strength of the vibration through settings?

I've seen that the Galaxy phones have a vibration setting that can be adjusted but I can't seem to find something similar on the Nexus 4.

Comment: Did you try [this suggestion](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/28912/1465)? I agree with the comments there that it may solve the problem despite not changing the strength.

Comment: I've played with it, it mostly reminded me of how weak this vibration is. I've had phones where I could tell they were virbrating when it was on my desk upstairs and this one I can barely tell when its in front of me and I'm looking at it.

Comment: I just wanted to Ditto what Ryan said above. Nexus S Vibrate was more noticeable when it was upstairs than its speaker. I can't feel the N4's Linear Oscillator motor at all when its on the desk. Guess its in the wrong direction.. Silly LG.

Comment: One thing I've found is that the vibrate is felt more strongly on the edges of the phone than the front or back. Not that this is a particularly practical solution, but if one of the edges is touching a table, for example, rather than it laying flat on it's back, the vibrate is much more noticeable.

Comment: Have you considered that it might be a design feature? It's pretty surprising if you turn a phone to vibrate so it won't make a noise, and then put it on a desk, and the result is that it sounds like a woodpecker. If you want to *hear* your phone, don't set it to vibrate.

Comment: AS I mentioned in the question, it's hard to notice even in my pocket. Besides, while hearing it and feeling it often go together due to the nature of vibration, I generally care more about feeling it and it fails at that most times.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called [Trinity Kernal Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.derkernel.tkt&hl=en). It helps to adjust Vibartion intensity in Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4(only).
But the thing is your device should be Rooted. And its a paid App.

**The app supports the following:**
- Adjusting of CPU Min/Max Frequencies
- Selecting of CPU Governor
- CPU Governor settings
- Selecting of I/O Scheduler
- Adjusting of Max Screen Off Frequency (Galaxy Nexus only)
- Adjusting of all CPU Voltages
- Sound control: High Performance toggle + Volume boost (Galaxy Nexus only)
- Color control (Galaxy Nexus + Nexus 4 Only)
- Contrast control (Galaxy Nexus Only)
- **Adjusting of Vibration Strength (Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4 only)**
- USB Fast Charge Toggle (with plug check)
- Thermal Throttle Toggle (Galaxy Nexus only)
- Smart Reflex Autocomp Toggles (Galaxy Nexus only)
- Wifi PM Toggle (Steadier stream or better battery) (GN + N7 only)
- Menu with utility functions to make common tasks easier.
- Reboot Widgets to access common options from Homescreen
- CPU Temperature Widget (Galaxy Nexus + SGS3 + Nexus 7)
- Statusbar Temperature display on select widgets (GN + SGS3 + Nexus 7)
- Restores trivial settings on boot
- Frequency/Voltage settings restored on boot if chosen
- Crash Recovery (To get you out of boot loops)
- Optimizes system independent from init.d (Great for stock roms)

May be it will help you to solve your issue. Don't blame me for recommeding a Paid App

If you are interested just flash this [Kernal](http://www.derkernel.com/jb-mako.php) to support it

Answer (score 1):

[Vibration Config](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dunnow.software.vibrationTuner&hl=en_GB) claims to be able to increase the vibration strength of a Nexus 4 (and some other phones) and a few reviews indicate that it works. It does need root so as soon as I get around to rooting my Nexus I'll give it a go and report back.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the strength, but the direction. At least my Nexus 4 makes no noise if it vibrates while lying flat on the table. Lay it on the side, and it will wake the dead.

The axis of rotation should be paralell to the screen, not perpendicular. No amount of software will fix this hardware/design error.

Comment: I gave the same answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51150/danger-of-increasing-the-vibration-strength-of-phone/51162#51162), I hope it is not against policy.

Comment: Not against policy, but duplicate answers can be a strong indication of duplicate questions.