# Danger of increasing the vibration strength of phone

Tags: nexus-4, vibration

Are there any dangers or possible negative consequences to increasing the vibration strength of a phone? Ideas were damages to the motor, lower battery life or increased wear leading to a shorter operating life? I don't know how likely or possible these are.

Specifically I want to use [Vibration Config](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dunnow.software.vibrationTuner&hl=en_GB) to increase the strength of my [hopeless Nexus 4's vibration](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34952/improve-nexus-4-vibration-intensity).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the strength, but the direction. At least my Nexus 4 makes no noise if it vibrates while lying flat on the table. Lay it on the side, and it will wake the dead.

The axis of rotation should be paralell to the screen, not perpendicular. No amount of software will fix this hardware/design error.

Comment: [Here](http://qsoe.hu/stand.jpg) is a DIY stand, that will help the phone to vibrate in a noticable way.

Comment: This may be helpful information, but it doesn't really answer the question.