# How to increase sound and vibration

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, audio, vibration

I have a rooted Android 4.0 phone but the ringer volume and vibration strength for incoming calls is too low/weak for me.

Can I increase the ringer volume and vibration strength beyond the currently allowed maximum level?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [How can I boost the volume on my Droid's speaker?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1262/16575) / [How can I make my Samsung Galaxy Nexus volume go louder than what stock allows?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17319/16575) / [How can I increase the maximum speaker volume?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/19426/16575) / [How can I boost the music volume higher than the max limit?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30527/16575) / [Search: volume boost](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=volume+boost)

Comment: Thanks For These Links But what about Vibration>

Comment: The very same pattern: [search for "vibration increase"](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=vibration+increase) turns up e.g. [Increase vibrate strength](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28851/16575) / [Improve Nexus 4 Vibration Intensity](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/34952/16575). Just try the search box on this page to refine search terms; we've got these questions a lot, so you should find many similar, already answered questions.